# npm start returning an error

Tags: javascript, npm, meanjs, npm-start

I am having difficulty with an error when I run 'npm start' on my mean.js application. I will paste both the terminal output and the code from the file with the error.

Terminal:

```
/Users/developer/dev-projects/Central-Repo/node_modules/rcloader/index.js:39
    if (err) throw err;
             ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.csslintrc'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! meanjs@0.6.0 start: `gulp`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the meanjs@0.6.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/developer/.npm/_logs/2018-07-24T09_18_22_923Z-debug.log
```

Index.js: (error in 10th line of code)

```
var defaultFileGiven = (config.defaultFile !== undefined);
if (defaultFileGiven) {
if (finder.canLoadSync) {
  assign(config, finder.get(config.defaultFile));
} else {
  // push callbacks here that need to wait for config to load
  configPending = [];
  // force the async loader
  finder.get(config.defaultFile, function (err, defaults) {
    if (err) throw err;
    assign(config, defaults);

    // clear the configPending queue
    var cbs = configPending;
    configPending = null;
    cbs.forEach(function (cb) { cb(); });
  });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems .csslintrc file is not available in your project folder. You can re download this from the master branch and try again.

Comment: If you can go to this url where you should see the file: https://github.com/meanjs/mean and download the file separately and put into your project folder.

Comment: Are you familiar with mongodb as it relates to node.js and the mean stack? I had another question/error and am too lazy to start another thread.

Comment: Yes sure, let me know what type of problem you are facing with mongodb.

Comment: I am experiencing the following error when running 'mongo' from terminal within my mean app:

Comment: developer@Codys-MacBook-Pro-3:~/dev-projects/Central-Repo$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-07-24T06:38:53.326-0500 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed

Comment: That worked. But when I run 'npm start' on the entire application, it says that there is a 'MongoError.' Here is what I see:

Comment: name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]' }
[07:04:12] [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

Comment: have you tried to run nodemon using such command: nodemon app

Comment: This is the result from running 'nodemon app':

Comment: [nodemon] 1.18.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `gulp app`
[07:25:01] Using gulpfile ~/dev-projects/Central-Repo/gulpfile.js
[07:25:01] Task 'app' is not in your gulpfile
[07:25:01] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176728/discussion-between-chody-and-shahriat-hossain).